# Nested resource parameters with Rails and Backbone.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I've got this issue where I am seeing the incoming parameters nested incorrectly. Here's some of the setup:

In routes.config I've defined:

```
resources :events do
  resources :guests
end
```

As a result I end up with the right controller/action paths. The ones I'll call out here are specified as such:

```
POST   /events/:event_id/guests(.:format)                guests#create
```

no surprises here. Now in the Guest model I have an association with a Contact model such that A Guest belongs to a Contact and a Contact has many Guests. This works correctly. Nothing tricky here either.

The backbone.js model for this is defined as such:

```
define('GuestModel', [
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {

  var Guest = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: "id",
    url: function() {
      return '/events/' + this.get('event_id') + '/guests';
    }
  });

  return Guest;
});
```

A quick caveat to this: I am providing the backend API support for the frontend and the guy who is implementing the front end (as my immediate client) doesn't use the rails asset pipeline at all. I have no control over this and as a result this is the bit of code I can't really affect w/o first convincing him it's the way to go.

The problem is that in the GuestsController#create method I'm expecting to see params that look like this:

{ 
    :event_id => 1, 
    :guest => {
      :contact => { 
        ...all the contact parameters...
      }, 
      ...other guest params...
     }, 
     ...other railsy parameters...
    }

Instead I'm getting:

{ 
    :event_id => 1, 
    :contact => { 
      ...all the contact parameters... 
    },
    ...other guest params...,
    ...other railsy parameters...
   }

Because there's no :guest object in the params at the top level, none of this is picked up by the standard Rails create behavior and I find myself having to basically pull out the contact and other guest params and put them manually into a hash object. Or I can pull out the event id and other Railsy params and use the params as a whole.  But I can't believe this hasn't ever been seen or addressed by someone before me so I'm hoping someone can either tell me what the standard approach to this is, or what I'm doing wrong at a more fundamental level.

Thanks in advance, and let me know if I've left out some information or code you need to see...

jd

Comment: this is just an opinion, but I think you do it right. Your client pays you for an API, so you deliver the API he requests. This is not RESTful as rails community understands it, but that's what your client wants... You can either advise your client to conform to a standard interface, or let him do as he wants. One option you have is to use an Adapter class that would parse the params and return a "standard" hash if need be ; this way you can provide both a standard interface and a custom one, and keep the business logic identical behind.

Comment: As a side note, i think this question would be more suited to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than SO. There is little objective answer possible to your question as it is more a matter of design choices.